# Exception in build with proguard

Tags: build.gradle, proguard, obfuscation, gradlew

I have a fat jar whcih include my package as well as all the dependencies. To obfuscate the jar ,I have addded proguard this is my gradle taks

```
def dependsDir = "${buildDir}/libs/dependencies/"
task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
  configuration 'proguard.conf'

  injars(layout.buildDirectory.file(inputJar))

  // As of Java 9, the runtime classes are packaged in modular jmod files.
  libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/java.base.jmod", jarfilter: '!**.jar', filter: '!module-info.class'

  libraryjars "${dependsDir}"

  outjars(layout.buildDirectory.file(outputJar))
}
```

but when running i m getting exception

Unexpected error while preverifying:
Class       = [freemarker/ext/jsp/TagTransformModel]
Method      = [getWriter(Ljava/io/Writer;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/io/Writer;]
Exception   = [proguard.evaluation.IncompleteClassHierarchyException] (Can't find common super class of [freemarker.ext.jsp.JspWriterAdapter] (with 1 known super classes: freemarker.ext.jsp.JspWriterAdapter) and [java.io.Writer] (with 2 known super classes: java.io.Writer, java.lang.Object))

freemarker-2.3.32.jar is already present in my dependencies folder.

tell me how to fix this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Trying to fix it. I will let you know if i find the solution

Comment: This helped to me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58718671/12416141.

Just add `dontoptimize` and `dontpreverify` options to proguard configuration.

But now my main class does not work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just added dependency to my project on [javax.servlet.jsp-api](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api/2.3.3) solved my problem.